# Already set "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"

Tags: android, android-intent

When I start activity from a BroadCastReceiver, the exception "**Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**" will happened. The follow is my receiver code

```
public class LogoutReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String LOGOUT_ACTION = "com.ss.ee.logout";
private Logger logger = new Logger(LogoutReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), true);

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    logoutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK );
    //logoutIntent.putExtra("logout", true);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

You can see it ,I have set **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** already. 
I want to point another thing. I send the broadcastreceiver from my HTTP request which in a work thread. The code most like this:

```
Handler mDelivery = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
mDelivery.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyAppApplication.getInstance().sendBroadcast(new Intent(LogoutReceiver.LOGOUT_ACTION));
            }
        });
```

Anyone meet the problems? Any help is great.

Comment: You should use runOnUIThread http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for this question. My mistake cause this problems. Please have a look the point of problem.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
logoutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK );
//logoutIntent.putExtra("logout", true);
context.startActivity(intent);//Here should be logoutIntent 
}
```

Sorry for this.